# OnMouseOver Image Display Text on Cursor

Tags: html, css, popup

This want the text box that appears under the image in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ANKwQ/5/
to instead have the same effect this does: http://xurday.com , when you hover over images, meaning it will move around with the cursor while it is in the image.

```
div {
display: none;
border:1px solid #000;
height:30px;
width:290px;
margin-left:10px;
```

}

```
a:hover + div {
display: block;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ANKwQ/3265/):

Basicly all you need:

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    $('div').css('top', currentMousePos.y);
    $('div').css('left', currentMousePos.x);
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:30px;
    width:290px;
    margin-left:10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```